# bbcode and preg_replace for images: closing slash is missing

Tags: php, preg-replace, bbcode

I have got a bbcode question, because I would like to add  a picture with bbcodes.

This code

```
preg_replace('|\[img\](.*)\[\/img\]|', '<img src="$1" class="wide" />', $content);
```

inserts the picture.

The problem ist that in the html code the `/` before the closing bracket is misssing:

```
<img src="bilder/a2.jpg" class="wide" >
```

Where is the mistake?

Thank you

Comment: [why don't you use a BBCode parser?](http://php.net/bbcode)

Comment: When I run it, it works fine. Something else must be going on. Do you perhaps make XHTML into HTML later? The closing slash is not needed in HTML.

Comment: Can you reproduce it? This does seem right: https://eval.in/40798

Comment: I just saw, that the code in the source-code is ok! The error comes in chromes and in safaris "firebug" (this code-checker addon). What do you think. Is this code best practise in the meaning of secure?